# class.getResourceAsStream doesn't find File

Tags: java, file-io, resources

## The Problem

I am loading a yaml-configuration in a Minecraft-Server plugin, but it can't find the file / returns null. I tried everything.

I checked if the file also exists in the `jar`-file and renamed the file to `game_settings.yml.txt`, too, but with no success.

#### My package structure

```
+- src [resource root]
  +- my.package
    +- MyClass.java
    +- game_settings.yml
```

## What I tried

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("game_settings.yml"); // null
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("game_settings.yml"); // null
MyClass.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("game_settings.yml"); // null
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("game_settings.yml"); // null
```

The weird thing is that when I use `getResource()`, it always finds the path. So Java actually knows that the file is there.

EDIT: The file is not found in the package, but I can see it in the jar. Why is the file invisible for Java?

## Sources

- [getResourceAsStream() is returning null. Properties file is not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053059/getresourceasstream-is-returning-null-properties-file-is-not-loading)
- [getResourceAsStream returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null)
- [Class.getResource() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581687/class-getresource-returns-null)
- [Class.GetResource Returns A Null](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/279717-classgetresource-returns-a-null/)
- [Java .class.getResourceAsStream()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977851/java-class-getresourceasstream)

Comment: Can you check by pitting yaml  file in the resource root?

Comment: `getResource()` and `getResourceAsStream()` require different types of paths, as you have found out. I think you have found out that *guessing* is not a valid debugging technique either. Reading the actual documentation and using a step-debugger are valid techniquest.

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: The problem is, that you can't use a step debugger because of Bukkit: https://bukkit.org/. It has just a logger, where I have to log for debugging. With the solution of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563622/reading-txt-file-from-jar-fails-but-reading-image-works, I can get more detail, like FileNotFound.

Comment: Now, the Plugins tells me that the file cannot be found but, as shown above, the file is in the jar-file.

Comment: I got a solution! It seems that _**Bukkit** doesn't reload all resources_ with the command `/reload`. When I **completely restart the server**, it will find the file.